# What is the best caching solution for website with a lot of content?

Tags: 8, caching

We are building a website with over a million nodes. Those nodes also have paragraphs which increases the number of entities. Therefore, the cache tables are getting bigger and bigger, especially the cache_entity and cache_render tables.

What is the best way to avoid the database to get too big (we're talking hundred of gigabytes) ? Is memcache a solution here or is it just deporting the problem of disk space ?

The basic cron task doesn't clear the tables. We were also thinking about setting a cron task to execute "drush cr".

According to that [post](https://docs.acquia.com/article/managing-large-cache-render-tables-drupal-8) and that [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2526150), Drupal 8.4 will have a better cache table management.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to comment what you've added to the answer. See also the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2891281. Your cache strategy depends on how many nodes you want to serve from the cache, what we don't know.

Comment: Alright, so that would solve my db size problem but then I should think about what page I want to serve from the cache. We were thinking about that because a lot of content are considered as "archives" so less important.

Comment: Then this depends on the more important ones. If you can afford to cache them in memory, then go for Memcached or Redis.

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll look into Memcache or Redis. Any preference on your side ?

Comment: In D8 Redis has picked up quite some momentum, see https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/redis

Comment: Always do what you can to divert any work away from MySQL to caching layers. Setup a memory cache with 192M to start and look into adding Varnish or similar. Are you also running PHP 7.1?

Comment: Yep of course we are using 7.1, I don't know if varnish is useful in my case. The problem is the potential volume I'm facing as a million nodes means a million consultable url.

Comment: I'm not sure what that comment means. Even though you have PHP 7.x, you should still have caching layers. Even in the D6 days there were sites that had 6 to 7 figures of nodes.

Comment: Well to me Varnish is good for high traffic websites (I might be wrong there) where my problem is just high volume of datas :-)

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution could be to compress those cache tables where the typical values to cache are quite big and allow for a high compress ratio. I think render caches fit that description very well.

See e.g. issue [[#1281408]](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1281408) and a [comment on another issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/redis/issues/2826332#comment-11791367) mentioned in comment #23.